# Does wdWord not work in Selection.EndKey

Tags: vba, ms-word

w8, 32 bit, ms office 2010, ms word, vba

I am creating a macro that finds a given string across a word file, and does some changes in each find instance.

Once the string is found, I want to extend the selection to the End of current word boundary. for which I am giving the following.

```
lenPos = Selection.EndKey(Unit:=wdWord, Extend:=wdExtend)
```

The above line is throwing a 4120 Bad parameter error.

when used without a function, just as:

```
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdWord, Extend:=wdExtend
```

Eeven then it is giving error.
Whereas, here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195593.aspx
and here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838950.aspx
it is saying wdWord is a valid wdUnits which should have worked here.

When I change wdWord to WdLine it works.

What I am missing?

So, how to I extend a FIND selected string to the

1. start of
2. end of

the current word, (words separated by white space or punctuation.)

Edit
say, I am searching "de"
and it is found in the word "abcdefgh".
The selected part is "de".

I now want to select first
1. "abcde" 
and then to select 
2. "defgh" 
so that I only have a part of currently matched word.
Thanks.

Comment: However this is working           Selection.MoveStart Unit:=wdWord, Count:=-1           and               Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with MoveStart and MoveEnd. My suggestion would be to use two Ranges in addition to the "Find" Range - one for going to the start of the word, the other for going to the end. For example:

```
Sub FindStartThenEnd()
    Dim rngFind As word.Range
    Dim rngStart As word.Range
    Dim rngEnd As word.Range

    Set rngFind = ActiveDocument.content
    With rngFind.Find
        .Text = "de"
        If .Execute Then
            Set rngStart = rngFind.Duplicate
            Set rngEnd = rngFind.Duplicate
            rngStart.MoveStart Unit:=wdWord, Count:=-1
            rngEnd.MoveEnd Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
            Debug.Print rngStart
            Debug.Print rngEnd
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

It's also possible to use wildcards, but that might be a bit difficult to implement if you want first one, then the other. Turn on wildcards then use the following pair of search terms:

```
<*de
de*>
```

These search for : beginning of word, any number of characters preceding "de" /
"de" followed by any number of characters to the end of a word.

As to the WdCharacterUnit not working with EndKey: The action must be something that works in the Word UI. There is no combination with the End key that will select a word, which is why wdWord is not allowed. MoveRight and MoveLeft should accept it, which would be the equivalent of Ctrl+Shift+Right / Left arrow.